# ElasticSearch & Mongo

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

Very newbie question I assume.. I started playing around with ES and MongoDB and I'm trying to move data out a SQL DB as an exercise. 
I can't help but wonder, what data would I store in Mongo and what in ES? Can I store everything in ES? Assume *big* data load, as in price trends.

Comment: Well it really depends on what you want, normally elasticsearch is for lots and lots of content you want to do text search, it was optimized for that. You can store everithing in elastic seach, but I don't think thats usual. This may help you https://www.compose.io/articles/mongoosastic-the-power-of-mongodb-and-elasticsearch-together/

Comment: Thanks @dege, the article helps.

Comment: I have tended to store that part of the content relevant to search on Elasticsearch and keep the expanded data on Mongo. This allows me to present the top-ranking hits to the user in the presentation layer. I pull out details from Mongo when the user selects one of the hits for which s/he wants further details furnished.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To begin with, MongoDB is so-called a document store. Key feature of such concept is that is stores schema-dynamic documents:

- Each record in a document collection can have a different structure
- Types of each records can be different
- Document properties (columns) can have nested structures

It's not schema-free, it's schema-dynamic (or flexible schema). To get into the concept, you can find a great tutorial here: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/

MongoDB is the most widely used document store - please, see http://db-engines.com/en/system/MongoDB.

It has "drivers" for most programming languages, enabling rapid development. You can dive into Mongo quite quickly, there are a lot of tutorials and official Mongo University - a great course for developers and DBAs.

In short terms it supports indexing, aggregations, filters, load balancing, sharding, replications (replica sets) etc. Data is stored and transferred in a BSON format (http://bsonspec.org/).

A good comparison of MongoDB vs RDBMS concepts can be found in this official reference: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/

What is it good for? It enables agile development, where schema can change over a period of time, especially form based data, user generated content, location based data, user profiles and more. It also enables storing large documents (up to 16MB each).

Now, Elasticsearch is not a database. It is a search engine with some great aggregation capabilities (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html - make sure you check out Metrics, Buckets and Pipeline aggregations).

Typical RDBSM is not designed for full-text searches or loosely structured data. Queries in ES can return results much faster than any database (e.g. seconds in RDBMS compared to milliseconds in ES). You need to remember that a key is to design indexes well, and that they will take your disk space.

There is a very detailed article comparing both in regards to performance, you may find it useful: http://blog.quarkslab.com/mongodb-vs-elasticsearch-the-quest-of-the-holy-performances.html.

You can actually use both successfully - MongoDB will store your data, where ES will be used as serving layer (search, aggregations etc.).

Comment: tldr: **Elasticsearch is not a database** -> Uses meta indexing for searching. Used in conjunction with DB's such as mongo. Best answer. What I don't like is why you even mention Pricings and cloud systems ? Irrelevant.

Comment: You're right, pricing is irrelevant. I'll remove it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a big difference between mongodb and ES.
MongoDB is a database which was design in order to store data in it and query thats, while elasticsearch is an lucene base indexer in which you should only index data for searches and should not trust elastisearch. even though you can use store:true in elastic search, it is not recommended and i wouldn't rely on that for important data.